# Is it possible to set an Android app's versionName to match a dependency's resolved version?

Tags: android, gradle, groovy

I'm working on an Android app where 95% of the functionality is contained within a library I wrote. This same library will be used across 30+ apps, and I would like to not have to set each app's version manually. Instead, I want to set the app's `versionName` based on the library's resolved version (since it isn't explicitly specified in the `build.grade` file).

Here is my current `build.gradle` file for the app:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 27
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.commentsold.demo"
        minSdkVersion 18
        targetSdkVersion 27
        multiDexEnabled true
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

buildscript {
    repositories {
        maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.+'
    }
}

apply plugin: 'io.fabric'

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    implementation 'com.github.CommentSold:Android-CommentSoldKit:1+'
}

android {
    defaultConfig {
        versionCode 1
        versionName ***SET_THIS_NAME_BASED_ON_Android-CommentSoldKit***
    }
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Notice, the placeholder **SET_THIS_NAME_BASED_ON_Android-CommentSoldKit**. That is where I would like to substitute something like "1.0.0".

Comment: I am curious, if any new build is released for any of the 30 apps, the version of library would be changed?

Comment: Why don't you use automati versioning using `Git`?

Comment: @CoderP for any of the 30+ apps, their versionName should match or be based upon the CommentSoldKit library's semantic version. if CommentSoldKit is then updated and a new version is available, then yes, all 30+ apps could pull in the new CommentSoldKit (which would in-turn update each app's versionName)

Comment: @MarcEstrada can you expound on what you're asking? i am using `Git` and I am tagging/versioning CommentSoldKit already.

Comment: Ok, this is what I would say, tagging/versioning, but for all apps. All aps uses the same code and are organized with flavors in the same project? Or all of 30 are independent projects?

Comment: @MarcEstrada all 30 are independent projects

Comment: Wow, understand now what you want

Answer (score 0):

You can define shared variables in your project's root `build.gradle` via something like this:

```
buildscript {
    ext {
        my_lib = "com.github.CommentSold:Android-CommentSoldKit:1.0.0"
    }
}
```

Then inside each of your app's build.gradle, you can do

```
def common = rootProject.ext
dependencies {
    implementation common.my_lib
}
```

Is this what you are looking for?

Comment: no, not exactly. I want the dependency to keep its "1+" syntax as shown in my original example, and then set a variable based on the resolved version (ex: 1.0.3)